# MATCH & paste in Excel

Tags: excel

Googling this wasn't productive, hence posting here.

I have data available in columns D and E. When adding numbers into column A, I need Excel to check if it exists in column D. I'm able to do that with MATCH function (no match for A1, however match exists between A2 and D3).

What I'm missing is that if there is a match between columns A and D, I would also need to paste data in column E into column B. I.e. as a match is found for cell A2 in cell D3, cell B2 should be filled with data in cell E3 (text "Yellow").

I have left column C for the formula, but that's not important. How to tackle such a thing? Not essential to definitely use MATCH.

```
    A     B     C      D     E

   13          #N/A   25    Blue
   11                  5    Red
                      11    Yellow
                       9    White
                      33    Yellow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forumla you are looking for is VLOOKUP.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,D:E,2,FALSE)
```

This will find the value in A2 in column D and return the value in column E, which it finds an exact match.

Put this formula in B2 and copy it down as needed.